# How stop width when img reaches max-height?

Tags: css, image, width, aspect-ratio

**Situation**: I have a site with images/pictures and I would like to set them nicely.
**Problem**: In my CSS max-height property works fine but when any image/pic reach the max-height 15% the width of any image doesn't stop, they get wider and wider by resizing browser or using wider resolution.
**Question**: The pictures aren't nice, so how to stop img width auto resizing when any img reaches the max 15% height on my page?
**What I need**: I want a totally fluid site by percentages and img widths doesn't matter, only the max-height must be 15% and keeping the img ratio in any situation.

At the moment the  tag properties are in my css:

```js
img { 
  height: auto;
  max-height: 15%;
}
```

Comment: And you're certain there is no width definition for your images? You need to make sure width is either not set at all, or set to `auto`.

Comment: Thanks mate and you are right. But in any CSS reference i can ready: THE DEFAULT WIDTH AND HEIGHT PROPERTY: auto...
Fantastic. Thanks.